# How to properly associate this objects two constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to create my own reminder app with javascript, so basically i can create a set of reminders like a category (work, school , programming reminders, etc). And each of this can have their reminders like on work category i can have list of reminders there and so on. I also want to save the sets and their reminders on a localstorage and recreate them again on the page. Of course the list of reminders should be on the set it belongs.

Before i do the page i really want to model this first and i decided to go on oop approach as a practice and i am figuring out how to associate them here's what i got so far..

```
    var ReminderSet = function(set){
      this.set = set; //could be work, school , etc 

    }


    var Reminders = function(new_reminder){
      this.reminders = new_reminder; // a new reminder
    }

    ReminderSet.prototype.reminders = new Reminders();

    ReminderSet.prototype.printSet = function(){
      console.log(this.set, this.reminders); /* gives the ff output 
work { reminders: 'finish task on time' }
school { reminders: 'study on chem' }*/
    }

    var workReminders = new ReminderSet("work"); // create a new set of reminder
    var schoolReminders = new ReminderSet("school"); // create a new set of reminder

    workReminders.reminders = new Reminders("please the boss"); //add a new reminder to work
    workReminders.reminders = new Reminders("finish task on time");//add a new reminder to work
    schoolReminders.reminders = new Reminders("finish projects"); //add new reminder to school
    schoolReminders.reminders = new Reminders("study on chem"); //add new reminder to school

    workReminders.printSet(); 
    schoolReminders.printSet();
```

The problem is it wont let me create more than one reminder for the set, i hope you can help me with this thank you! Just to be clear i only been learning javascript for 3 months and this is my first time doing oop although i made some previous task projects before but i think it's important to really get familiar with oop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're only able to add a single reminder, is because you're not building a collection of reminders. Each time you set the new reminder, you're overwriting the previous reminder.

I've rewritten the code you posted a little, to use what I believe are more intuitive property names, but also to build a collection of reminders within each `ReminderSet`.

```js
var ReminderSet = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.reminders = [];
}

ReminderSet.prototype.add = function (reminder) {
  this.reminders.push(reminder);
  return this;
}

ReminderSet.prototype.list = function() {
  console.log(this.reminders);
}

var Reminder = function (description) {
  this.description = description;
}


var work = new ReminderSet('work')
  .add(new Reminder('Get to work on time!'))
  .add(new Reminder('Finish all my work!'));

var school = new ReminderSet('school')
  .add(new Reminder('Finish my coursework'))
  .add(new Reminder('Study for my exams!'));

work.list();
school.list();
```

Comment: i really glad for the naming it really easy to understand thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the functions as a template to be filled out when creating new instances of it, rather than making them their own variable.

```
   function ReminderSet(set){
      this.set = set; //could be work, school , etc 

    }


    function Reminders(new_reminder){
      this.reminders = new_reminder; // a new reminder
    }

    ReminderSet.prototype.reminders = new Reminders();

    ReminderSet.prototype.printSet = function(){
      console.log(this.set, this.reminders); /* gives the ff output 
work { reminders: 'finish task on time' }
school { reminders: 'study on chem' }*/
    }

    var workReminders = new ReminderSet("work"); // create a new set of reminder
    var schoolReminders = new ReminderSet("school"); // create a new set of reminder

    workReminders.reminders = new Reminders("please the boss"); //add a new reminder to work
    workReminders.reminders = new Reminders("finish task on time");//add a new reminder to work
    schoolReminders.reminders = new Reminders("finish projects"); //add new reminder to school
    schoolReminders.reminders = new Reminders("study on chem"); //add new reminder to school

    workReminders.printSet(); 
    schoolReminders.printSet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an array as property of `class` and use an object where property name is reminder name and value can be any type

```js
class Reminders {
  constructor() {
    this.reminders = [];
  }
  setReminder(key, prop) {
    const reminder = {
      type: key,
      value: prop
    };
    this.reminders.push(reminder);
    return this;
  }
  getReminder(key) {
    return this.reminders.filter(({type}) => type === key)
  }
}

let reminders = new Reminders()

reminders.setReminder("work", ["a", "b"]);

let work = reminders.getReminder("work");

reminders.setReminder("school", "study")

let school = reminders.getReminder("school");

reminders.setReminder("do stuff", "stuff")

let stuff = reminders.getReminder("do stuff");

for (let [{type, value}] of Object.values([work, school, stuff])) {
  console.log(`reminder type:${type}, reminder value:${value}`)
}
```